# $(a, b]\subset\bigcup_i(a_i, b_i]\Rightarrow(f(a), f(b))\subset\bigcup_i[f(a_i), f(b_i)]$, when $f$ is increasing and continuous from right

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is increasing and continuous from the right. If the half-open interval $(a, b]$ is contained in a union of half-open intervals, $$(a, b]\subset\bigcup_i(a_i, b_i],$$ then the open interval $(f(a), f(b))$ is contained in the union of closed intervals, $$(f(a), f(b))\subset\bigcup_i[f(a_i), f(b_i)].$$

Literally I have no idea how to prove this. How should I use the fact that $f$ is increasing or right-continuous? Any hints or help is appreciated.